# How to make a simulation of UR5 in Gazebo?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to make a simulation for a UR5 robot which is used for pick and place. How can I use a camera in order to develop an algorithm for visualization?
Your help is much appreciated, hence I am new to ROS and Gazebo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312007/how-to-make-a-simulation-of-ur5-in-gazebo?/) by [Piyumal](https://answers.ros.org/users/39315/piyumal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-01-04**:
I'm not sure how to add a camera, but I would start with http://wiki.ros.org/ur_gazebo and make sure you are comfortable with the basic UR5 simulation first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I could say you have two option: First, if you need to attach a camera on the end-effector of UR5 (or any link ), you need to get the [ur_gazebo](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_gazebo) package and install it from the source, then you need to edit the xacro file of the robot `....../ur_description/urdf/ur5.urdf.xacro`  and there you can attach the camera to any link by following the same steps in the  [SensorPlugin tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins). i just tried it, you can see screenshot (the weight box represent the camera):[image: image description].

Second option: you mention that you are working on pick and place application, you might need to create your own environment where you will use the UR5 robot. In that case, you can attach your camera anywhere in the environment following the same steps in the  [SensorPlugin tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins).
Hope this can help :)

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Piyumal](https://answers.ros.org/users/39315/piyumal/) on 2019-01-30**:
Thank you very much.